# DatePicker JQuery UI valiadtion to date >= from date

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, razor, jquerydatetimepicker

Can anyone tell me how to do validation through class name (i.e) **.datepicker**

Here is the demo to have a validation for **to date >= from date**

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
changeYear: true,
dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy", 
yearRange: '2006:' + (new Date().getFullYear() +1)
}).datepicker("setDate", "0");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sharmilashree/YdeY8/482/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with using `moment.js`. However, if you for some reason don't want to, or can't, here is a solution for your fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/jonofan/YdeY8/483/

```
$('.datepicker').on('change', function() {
      var fromParts = $('#CheckInDate').val().split('-');       
      var toParts = $('#CheckOutDate').val().split('-');

      //please put attention to the month (parts[0]), Javascript counts months from 0:
      // January - 0, February - 1, etc

      var fromDate = new Date(fromParts[2],fromParts[0]-1,fromParts[1]); 
      var toDate = new Date(toParts[2],toParts[0]-1,toParts[1]); 

      if ( fromDate >= toDate ) {
        alert('Check in must be before check out!')
      }
    })
```

The reason you must split your date into parts is because the javascript [`Date()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object only parses specific formats, and you cannot custom formats. This is why it is nice to use a library like `moment.js`, as it will handle everything very flexibly.

From experience, using string splitting to parse dates becomes problematic in the event that you want to change the date format. Say in 6 months you wanted to change your dates from `dd-mm-yy` to `dd/mm/yy`; you will have to go and update your string splitting code.

Comment: Thanks for response. Is there any way to put checkInDate.datepicker and checkOutDate.datepicker functions inside .datepicker function. Because i need to access the control fields via class name and not via control name.

Comment: @Ammu you can certainly access them via `$('.datepicker')` but you need to know which is check in, and which is check out. For that I think you probably still need the ids. Appreciate if you could 'mark as answer' if this was useful.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [momentJS](https://momentjs.com/) to validate if you date is before or equals. 
A simple code like :

```
if(moment(fistDate).isBefore(moment(secondDate)) || moment(firstDate).isSame(moment(secondDate)) {

}
```

In this example, the first date represent the value of your datetimepicker and the second date is whatever you want it to be since you never told what it was.

Comment: Thanks for response. My coding is working fine.Is there any way to put checkInDate.datepicker and checkOutDate.datepicker functions inside .datepicker function. Because i need to access the control fields via class name and not via control name.